# while i am running the hibernate example it shows an message like this

Tags: hibernate, derby

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<clinit>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:65)
    at com.Hibernate.Chapter1.TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the jars related commons.
I think you missed the following jar or related one..

**apache-commons.jar**